# Handle push notification while in phone call ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, phone-call

I can't handle push notifications when my app is in background and the phone is in a call, this doesn't occurs when the app is in foreground and user gets a phone call  (in all other scenarios it works well).  Another thing is that this only happens when the app use a Production Push Notification Certificate, I tested this with a development certificate and it works.

The push is a *silent push* (content-available enabled) so I could handle it in backgroud using `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`

Comment: Development push SSL certificate will only work if you attach your iPhone with your mac and directly compile on your device. Production push SSL certificate will work when you create the app file or .ipa file and install that on device.

Comment: Yes, I know.  I generate an .ipa to test this, I get push correctly but no in the scenario I explained in the post.